# ! LaTeX Error: Command \removefromreset already defined

Tags: macros, errors

There are ready files for preparing Latex document. I used .cls template file and it has below code:

```
\newcommand{\@removefromreset}[2]{{%
  \expandafter\let\csname c@#1\endcsname\@removefromreset
  \def\@elt##1{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname c@##1\endcsname\@removefromreset
    \else
      \noexpand\@elt{##1}%
    \fi}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname cl@#2\endcsname{%
    \csname cl@#2\endcsname}}}
```

However, when I run my .tex file, an error occurs "! LaTeX Error: Command \removefromreset already defined"

Could you please help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The code snippet you showed can't produce that error because it defines `\@removefromreset`, with an `@`. Please show us the complete code which produces the error you mention.

Comment: It looks like somebody copied the `remreset.sty` code over to the class file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the LaTeX release from 2018/04/01 the `\@removefromreset` command is part of the LaTeX kernel.

The code by D. Carlisle was in `remreset.sty` (its author is D. Carlisle) and has been incorporated into the kernel. With any newer LaTeX version since 2018/04/01 there must be a conflict with a copied over code from `remreset.sty`. `remreset` is now declared obsolete.

The only way to remove the error is to remove the `\newcommand{\@removefromreset}...` from the class file.

The loading of `remreset` is also discouraged: (From `remreset.sty`):

```
%... header omitted here

% \LoadClass{book}
% \@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}

% 2018: package obsoleted as the command is defined in the LaTeX format.

\@ifundefined{@removefromreset}{%
\def\@removefromreset#1#2{{%
  \expandafter\let\csname c@#1\endcsname\@removefromreset
  \def\@elt##1{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname c@##1\endcsname\@removefromreset
    \else
      \noexpand\@elt{##1}%
    \fi}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname cl@#2\endcsname{%
    \csname cl@#2\endcsname}}}%
}{%
\PackageWarningNoLine{remreset}
    {The remreset package is obsolete:\MessageBreak
     \noexpand\@removefomresset is defined}%
}
```

Comment: I loaded remreset you've defined and erased the lines I've copied. It worked, thanks!!

Comment: @user178777: I have not defined `remreset`. `remreset` is obsolete and the macro is contained in the LaTeX kernel for almost one year by now....

Comment: Oh I got it. I comment out only removefromreset lines I've mentioned and so there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your `.cls` and can change things, remove or comment out the "new" definition of `\@removefromreset`. If you don't have access, then you can capture the original definition of `\@removefromreset` before you load the class and then restore it afterwards:

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@removefromreset\@removefromreset % Store \@removefromreset
\let\@removefromreset\relax
\makeatother

\documentclass{<your-class>} % Load your document class

\makeatletter
\let\@removefromreset\old@removefromreset % Restore \@removefromreset
\makeatother
```